# C++ operator lookup misunderstanding

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading, operator-precedence

I have a trouble with next case:

```
template<typename T>
void test(const T &ref){
     cout << "By reference";
}

template<typename T>
void test(const T *ptr){
     cout << "By pointer";
}
```

Any parameter that I sent to the `test()` method will always pass to overloading with reference. Even this:

```
int *p = 0; test(p);
```

Can someone tell me why reference has so high priority and the place in standart where to read about this.

Oh... I was inattentive! I have to specify both const and non-const overloading for a pointer case:

```
template<typename T>
void test(const T &ref){
     cout << "By reference";
}

template<typename T>
void test(T *ptr){
     cout << "By pointer";
}

template<typename T>
void test(const T *ptr){
     cout << "By const pointer";
}
```

Comment: Side note: After removing the templates and replacing `T` by `int` the pointer overload is chosen by g++ 4.8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `const T *` means that `T` is `const` but not `T *`.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
void test(const T &ref){
     std::cout << "By reference\n";
}

template<typename T>
void test( T * const ptr){
     std::cout << "By pointer\n";
}


int main()
{
    int *p;
    test(p);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use `typedef T * PtrT`, and then change `T * const` to `const PtrT`.

```
template <typename T>
using PtrT = T *;

template<typename T>
void test(const PtrT<T> ptr){
     std::cout << "By pointer\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which type is used in template, is it int or int*? I suspect that you inspecting T to be int, but compiler interpret T as a int* and use reference template.

Try to use

```
test<int>(p);
```

to specify type explicity

Comment: You do not answer "Can someone tell me why reference has so high priority and the place in standart where to read about this."